# Install AzureAD module on Debian

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Is it possible to install the AzureAD module to Powershell-6.0.0.alpha on Debian?

The error I receive:

```
PS /home/user> Set-PSRepository -name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted
PS /home/user> Install-Module AzureAD
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Unable to load DLL  
'api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll': 
The specified module could not be found.   
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
At /opt/microsoft/powershell/6.0.0-alpha.18/Modules/PowerShellGet/1.1.2.0/PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage
   :InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.DllNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestModuleManifestCommand,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement
  .Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

It complains a `dll` is missing, how to fix it (in Linux there are not dlls, aren't they?).

The powershell has been started with sudo superpowers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible as of today.